# Volley crashing app on service after long run

Tags: java, android, service, out-of-memory, android-volley

Am implementing a service to get updates from server as below:

```
public class Myupdates extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "AutoUpdates";
    private static final int started = 0;
    static SQLiteDatabase db;
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    private CountDownTimer timer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.db = openOrCreateDatabase("db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        //Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        isRunning = true;
    }

    int mCount = 1;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        //Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");

        //Creating new thread for my service
        //Always write your long running tasks in a separate thread, to avoid ANR
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (isRunning) {

                    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updates();
                        }
                    }, 0, 30000);

                }
                //Stop service once it finishes its task
                //stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        isRunning = false;

        //Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }

    /*
        HANDLE ADVERTS
    */
    protected void updates() {
        /*
            JSON
         */
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        final JSONObject manJson = new JSONObject();
        try {
            manJson.put("userid", "4444");
            manJson.put("version", "6.0");
            final String j = json.put("UPDATE", manJson).toString();
            final String base_url = "https://myweburl.com";
            // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, base_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //Log.i(TAG, "received "+response);
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                        String update = object.getString("UPDATE");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return;
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //perform operation here after getting error
                    return;
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    //pack message into json
                    try {
                        params.put("data", j.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //Log.i(TAG,"Map error: Unable to compile post");
                    }
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
            queue.add(stringRequest);
            // ends here
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.i(TAG,"ERROR: Unable to get setup settings");
        } // end exception write
        return;
    }

}
```

However, after a long running of the service the app is crashing with the below error:

> 03-08 00:19:41.570 11239-11253/com.mobiledatabook.com.dialcode
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
>                                                                                        Process: com.mobiledatabook.com.dialcode, PID: 11239
>                                                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes)
>   failed: Try again
>                                                                                            at java.lang.VMThread.create(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1029)
>                                                                                            at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:152)
>                                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:66)
>                                                                                            at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.mobiledatabook.com.dialcode.Myupdates.iDialAutoUpdates(Myupdates.java:128)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.mobiledatabook.com.dialcode.Myupdates$1$1.run(Myupdates.java:74)
>                                                                                            at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
>
> Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

Could someone help me to improve this code so as to avoid crashing the app after long running of the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is occurring because you are creating the `RequestQueue` instance multiple times by passing the activity `context`. You should create the instance once using an Application class and then use it again and again whenever needed. Create an application class like this,

```
public class AppController extends Application {
    private static AppController sInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    sInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {

            if (mRequestQueue == null) {
                mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            }

            return mRequestQueue;
        }

}
```

Then use it like this

```
RequestQueue queue=AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
```

**NOTE** : By passing the context to request queue again and again , you are filling up your ram, which leads to an `OutOfMemoryException` when no more space can be allocated

As mentioned in android's official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#java) ,

*A key concept is that the `RequestQueue` must be instantiated with the `Application` context, not an `Activity` context. This ensures that the `RequestQueue` will last for the lifetime of your app, instead of being recreated every time the activity is recreated (for example, when the user rotates the device).*