# Volley Out Of Memory issue V1.1.0

Tags: android, android-volley

I am getting this Out of memory issue from Volley. Currently, my
    request object creation is like this

```
if (reQuestQue == null) {
    reQuestQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
}
reQuestQue.add(mGsonRequest);`
```

I am getting this exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed:
Try again
           at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
           at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
           at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:135)
           at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:91)
           at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:67)
           at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:102)`
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: you need to clear a cache,volley library can store cache that is the main draw back of volley..

Comment: check this it might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068306/5370550

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49333574/8009433

Comment: @ZUNJAE  I am getting this exception looking for a fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this seems like I am recreating Request queue in my HTTP module per every request. To avoid that I used following singleton class in my module

`public class RequestQueSingleton {
    private static RequestQueSingleton sSoleInstance;
    private static RequestQueue reQuestQue;

```
private RequestQueSingleton(){}  //private constructor.

public static RequestQueSingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if (sSoleInstance == null){ //if there is no instance available... create new one
        sSoleInstance = new RequestQueSingleton();
        reQuestQue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    }

    return sSoleInstance;
}


public  synchronized RequestQueue getInstance() {
    Log.d("Request Que Obj",reQuestQue.hashCode()+"");
    return reQuestQue;
}}`
```