# Volley Queue Throwing OutOfMemoryError “pthread_create

Tags: android, android-volley

Every time i make a request i create a new Volley Request Queue:

```
public void initializeQueue(Context context){

    File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "Volley");
    this.queue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()), MAX_SIZE_THREAD_POOL);
    this.queue.start();
}
```

And when i finish my request i clean the variable

```
this.queue = null;
```

But when i make a lot of requests an error "Throwing OutOfMemoryError “pthread_create" it is thrown. So i searched the Internet and the conclusion was to initiate the queue only once.

But my question is, why does the memory keep rising if i create continuously new Queues? I make the variable nullable so the old queues are unreachable and GC collectable. Is there something else holding the queue?

**Note**
For context above is used the Application.

Thank you

Comment: GC is a periodic process. Even if you set your variable to `null` it doesn't guarantee that it will be GC'd immediately.

Comment: [try implementing a singleton pattern like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49333574/8009433)

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess for the problem would be :

**Context:**
You are passing the application context to the queue. So it will hold the reference till the application is alive.

**Code**

```
this.queue = null;
```

As this code will only clear reference it holds, and not the memory it occupies. Clearing it from memory its job of `GC` and you can't guarantee when `GC` will invoke.

Why would you want to create a new RequestQueue, for each request. You could check for `null`. create queue and use the same queue for further processing.

```
File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "Volley");
if( this.queue == null ){
   this.queue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()), MAX_SIZE_THREAD_POOL);
}
```

**Resources**:-
[Understanding context](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514), [Understanding reference](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83)